# How to show alamofire post request json value in table view using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

am try to convert json data to table view for swift 5 and also alamofire 5.2 version I got my response data from server itz also covert json but the problem is I can't show my response data in table view

```
class ViewController:  UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    struct User {
           var buzzyuser_id:Int?
           var buzzyuser_image:String?
            var buzzyuser_username:String?

           init(dic:[String: Any]) {
               self.buzzyuser_id = dic["buzzyuser_id"] as? Int
               self.buzzyuser_image = dic["buzzyuser_image"] as? String
               self.buzzyuser_username = dic["buzzyuser_username"] as? String
           }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!

    private var users = [User] ()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


        TableView.dataSource = self

        apiload()
    }
    func apiload() {
        let parameters: [String: Any] = ["userid": "1","start":"0"]
                  let url = "https://example.com/sample.php"

             AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
                 switch response.result{
                         case .success:
                            //success, do anything


                            if let json = response.value as? [String: Any] {
                                    for item in json {
                                                           // construct your model objects here
                                        self.users.append(User(dic:json))
                                                         }

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                              self.TableView.reloadData()
                            }
                            }

                            break
                 case .failure:

                                   return
                               }
             }
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell")
        let text = users[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}
```

debug value showed but list viewed only empty rows I can't find the error.

Comment: `let text = users[indexPath.row]; return cell!` And you don't do `let user = users[indexPath.row]; cell.textLabel.text = user.buzzyuser_username` (because  or something like that? You don't have "unused variable text" warning message?

Comment: sorry Larme i got only a label name not show my response data values

Answer (score 0):

your problem is here

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell")
    let text = users[indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

you are assigning the user value to the param "text" and then you are not assigning any value to the table view cell.

If you are trying... for example to show on the table the user "buzzyuser_username" then after

```
let text = user[indexPath.row]
```

you should add

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = text.buzzyuser_username
```

Also make sure you are registering the identifier "customcell" ... if you wish to load the cell from a xib file you can do it like this (note that with a xib file you can also create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell and make a tableview row with the user image id and username (that is what I think you are trying to archive)

```
self.table?.register(UINib.init(nibName: "YOUR_NIB_NAME", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customcell")
```

And after registering the reuse identifier you can then use it on your table view and if you also have added a custom class to your identifier you can force it on your tableview datasource implementation

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell") as! YOUR_CUSTOM_SUBCLASS
```